# Could a limiting result (in terms of convergence) imply an equivalence relation?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation, equivalence-relations, measurable-sets

1. Let $(X_n)$ be a martingale and a uniformly integrable collection of random variables. Given a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$, given that $\Phi\in\mathcal{F}_m$ and $X_n\rightarrow X_{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, knowing that
   $$|\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}-\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}|\leq\mathbb{E}\{|X_n-X_{\infty}|\}$$
   considering that, since $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\{|X_n-X_{\infty}|\}=0$ and therefore $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}-\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}|=0$ ,
    **is one allowed to state that $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$? In other terms, *in general* does it hold true that
   $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}-\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}|=0\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$$
   If so, why?**. 
   *Personally, I would end up with a limiting result in terms of relation between $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}$ and $\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$, NOT with an equivalence result, but I am pretty sure there is a flaw in my reasoning, since on Jacod-Protter I read the above discussed implication.*
2. Assuming that $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$ holds true, **can one state that this equality *implies* that $\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n\}=X_n$ a.s.?** I already know that $$\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n\}=X_n\hspace{0.2cm} a.s. \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$$ and I know how to prove this, but I do not know whether the other direction, that is $$\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n\}=X_n\hspace{0.2cm} a.s.$$ holds true as well.
    In general, this second question could be generalized as... *"is 'equal expectation' equivalent to 'equal conditional expectation'?* If so, one could condition on both sides of $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$ and eventually get that $\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n\}=X_n$ a.s., simply by definition of conditional expectation. 
   However, I am pretty sure that *"'equal expectation' IS NOT
   NECESSARILY equivalent to 'equal conditional expectation'"* and I think there are good counterexamples to show this.
   Henceforth, how can one prove this other direction in a good way
   **(which would let one eventually state that
   $\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}|\mathcal{F}_n\}=X_n$ a.s. $\iff$
   $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}\}$)?**

Comment: What is $\mathcal{F}_m$ here?

Comment: I have specified this right now by editing, sorry @Dasherman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implication is not true. Consider $X_n = 1/n,$ a deterministic sequence. This converges in $L^1$ to $X_\infty = 0$. Then for $\Phi = \Omega,$ we have $E[X_n1_\Phi] = 1/n\neq 0 = E[X_\infty 1_\Phi].$ The second implication is then also not true.

I suspect that you want $(X_n)$ to be a uniformly integrable martingale sequence, rather than just any sequence. Indeed, if $(X_n)_n$ is a uniformly integrable martingale sequence, we have by Doob's martingale convergence theorem that there exists $X_\infty$ such that $X_n\to X_\infty$ both a.s. and in $L^1$ and that the extended martingale property holds:
$$E[X_\infty| \mathcal{F}_n] = X_n.$$
See for example Theorem 2.12 here: http://math.tkk.fi/teaching/stokanal/lecture3.pdf

This then implies the first implication you wrote. If $\Phi \in \mathcal{F}_m$ for $m\leq n$, then by definition of a filtration, we have $\mathcal{F}_m\subset \mathcal{F}_n$, so we also have $\Phi \in \mathcal{F}_n$. We then have $E[X_n1_\Phi] = E[X_\infty 1_\Phi]$, by definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've forgotten this detail: $(X_n)$ is a martingale **and** a uniformly integrable collection of random variables. Given such additional details, do your conclusions hold true as well or do the two facts in the question hold true? @Dasherman

Comment: I've edited my answer. Note that the result is in fact somewhat stronger in this case: we need not a priori assume that there exists a limit $X_\infty,$ this is already guaranteed by $(X_n)$ being a uniformly integrable martingale.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed some important details. I have already let you know some of them, but I make a summary herebelow:

1. $(X_n)$ is a martingale and a uniformly integrable collection of random variables;
2. $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ is a filtration;
3. I consider $m\leq n$ and it is already correct that $\Phi\in\mathcal{F}_m$.

**Given also this third *clarification***, does your conclusion still hold true? @Dasherman

Comment: I've made an edit.

Comment: Ok, got it. At this point, if, for example, I had that $\mathbb{E}\{X_n1_{\Phi}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_m1_{\Phi}\}$, could I state that $|\mathbb E X_m1_{\Phi}-\mathbb E X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}|=|\mathbb E X_n1_{\Phi}-\mathbb E X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}| $ for all $n \geq m$ and, letting $n \to \infty$, $|\mathbb E X_m1_{\Phi}-\mathbb E X_{\infty}1_{\Phi}|=0$, which would imply, for all $\Phi \in \mathcal F_m$, that $\mathbb E S_m1_{\Phi}=\mathbb E S_{\infty}1_{\Phi}$? I am pretty sure that this result holds true, but I don't know exactly why it is so..is this related to your argument? @Dasherman

Comment: What is S here?

Comment: I mean $X$, please replace $S$ with $X$

Comment: Yes you could, but it's a bit of an odd way to go about it. It's easier to use the definition of conditional expectation and that $E[X_\infty|\mathcal{F}_m]=X_m$